# Site logo issue in international Stack Overflow site's profile page for anonymous users

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, localization

In the international Stack Overflow sites for logged-out users, when navigating to a specific user's profile in the top bar the partial text is truncated.

For an example in Russian Stack Overflow Community user profile, the text "на русском" is partially hide in the top bar. For the remaining page the logo is displaying properly.

Seems in other pages the HTML tag as `<span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow на русском</span>`, where as in the profile page the `_glyph` class is missing, which has the `height` attribute.

The issue can be reproduced in other site's community user profile too.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

> [image]

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

> [image]

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

> [image]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

> [image]

**System configuration:**

OS: Windows 10
Mozilla Firefox: 66.0 (64-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Microsoft Edge: 41.16299.15.0
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same thing. Worth noting that this behavior exists on MSO, too.